# Is the c++ primer making something wrong with the usage of `dynamic_cast`?

Tags: c++, access-control, dynamic-cast, private-inheritance

Quoted from C++ Primer 5th **19.2.1. The dynamic_cast Operator**

> A dynamic_cast has the following form:

```
dynamic_cast<type*>(e)
dynamic_cast<type&>(e)
dynamic_cast<type&&>(e)
```

> where type must be a class type and (ordinarily) names a class that has virtual
>   functions. In the first case, `e` must be a valid pointer (§ 2.3.2, p. 52); in the second, `e`
>   must be an lvalue; and in the third, `e` must not be an lvalue.
>
> In all cases,**the type of `e` must be either a class type that is publicly derived from
>   the target type, a public base class of the target type, or the same as the target
>   type. If `e` has one of these types, then the cast will succeed. Otherwise, the cast fails.**
>   If a dynamic_cast to a pointer type fails, the result is 0. If a dynamic_cast to a
>   reference type fails, the operator throws an exception of type `bad_cast`

However,here I've written a code snippet:

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A // note: *private* inheritance
{
  A* test() {
    return dynamic_cast<A*>(this);
  }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  if(b.test()==nullptr)
      throw 1;
}
```

In the code snippet above, `A` is just a private base of `B`, which is not taken into account by the c++ primer. However, **this code snippet could be compiled and run without error**. Has the primer made a mistake?

Comment: I don't get it, what's the matter?

Comment: @YSC According to primer,it the return of `test()` should be 0 .

Comment: @Quentin Was going to comment the same. But to be honest, it’s ridiculous that compilers aren’t forced to make this an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph throw in `-Werror` and you're good :)

Comment: The C++ primer made the mistake of trying to list all cases where `dynamic_cast` will succeed, and missed one.    Within member functions or friends of `B`, the base class `A` is accessible, so the `dynamic_cast` can succeed.

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast` throws an exception *only* if trying to cast to a *reference*.

Comment: *"According to primer,it should throw a exception."* - no (at least not in the bit you quote).  Rather, the Primer says a failing cast to a reference type will throw.  Failing casts to pointer types return `nullptr`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy But it's not `nullptr` in this case,either.

Comment: The "primer" just pulled the bolded passages out of thin air. They are plainly wrong. The standard says nothing of this sort.

Comment: @bigxiao: the Primer said failing dynamic casts to references throw - true.  We've told you failing casts to pointers return `nullptr`.  Both true.  The Primer tells you your code should fail - *that's* untrue.

Comment: @Quentin Oh I do that anyway. It’s annoying because it’s a frequent cause of errors here on Stack Overflow (and probably in quite a few code bases) and there’s no reason at all to allow it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is all in all an unfortunate phrasing on the primers part. It bunched the two types of casts one can do into one sentence, and then misspoke as a result.

Casting to a base class, doesn't require a runtime cast operation. It is, [as T.C. says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49381799/817643), purely a static construct. And like T.C. quoted, it requires an **accessbile** base, not public one. So your code is all good and well.

For a runtime cast (a downcast) the C++ standard places a requirement on the operand and the types involved in a dynamic cast in order for it to succeed. The class must be publicly derived, otherwise the implementation isn't obligated to make a successful cast down the inheritance chain. I mean, it could in theory make the cast successful, but according to the specification [*"the runtime check fails"*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.dynamic.cast#8.3), which doesn't leave much leeway.

But either way there's nothing wrong in your program that would make it fail to compile, nor is there anything there that would cause any sort of runtime error.

---

If we change your code to cast down, and not cast up, here's an [example that doesn't even build](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/183f7faa7f8eee0f):

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A // note: *private* inheritance
{
  A* test(B* p) {
    return dynamic_cast<A*>(p);
  }

  friend B* foo(A*);
};

B* foo(A* a) {
    return dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
}

int main()
{
  B b;
  *foo(&b);
}
```

`A` is an accessible base of `B` in `foo`, and yet, the cast is ill-formed.

---

The minimal change which will bring the primer back on course is to turn *"a class type that is **publicly** derived from the target type"* into *"a class type that is **accessibly** derived from the target type"*. Since there's nothing of the sort in the [publicly available errata](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html), we can guess it's an editorial mistake that is yet to be pointed out.

Comment: _"Otherwise, the cast fails."_ is maybe simplified too much, is it not?

Comment: @YSC - *"Otherwise, the cast fails"* Is a good rule to live by actually. A sidecast most probably would fail if the inheritance isn't public. I has a chance to see some code like that, let me see if I can reconstruct.

Comment: @bigxiao - Well, it's undefined by omission I suppose. The wording for how the cast behaves at runtime only mentions public bases.

Comment: "The C++ standard places a requirement" where? Please quote.

Comment: @StoryTeller So the standard also forget something?It should not be undefined here if the standard has considered such situation.

Comment: @n.m. - [\[expr.dynamic.cast\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.dynamic.cast#8) says numerous times "public base", not "accessible base".

Comment: @bigxiao - No, it didn't *forget*. It doesn't cover it, making it undefined by omission. And frankly, if you see the code sample I posted (which actually tests what the primer says, unlike your OP), you'll see it is indeed as the primer says.

Comment: But the primer never specifies cast down or up here,it just speaks of the using of `dynamic_cast`,literally "**in all cases**" ,which means here should generate a `nullptr` .

Comment: @bigxiao - I understand your question better now. Let me rephrase my answer.

Comment: Did bullet 8.3 just vanish?

Comment: @T.C. - Uh? I quote and link to it.

Comment: So where's the omission?

Comment: These places do not apply to the upcast case.

Comment: @T.C. - I had a very lively discussion the other day about the possibility of two sets of RTTI being possible in general for public and non-public bases. Still had it in mind.

Comment: @n.m. - Yes, but that is what I had in mind when originally posting. Should have read the OP more carefully. I implicitly assumed they do a downcast.

Comment: @bigxiao - I think you can take away from this that it's quite easy to get confused and misspeak. Probably even easier when one has a book editor that is not C++ savvy, that may mess with wording.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no **type checking** in upcast,even if I use the `dynamic_cast`? Or  there is no **public base requirement** in the upcast of `dynamic_cast` but still has **type checking**?

Comment: @bigxiao - There is a check in an upcast. But it's for an "accessible" base, not a "public" base. Accessibility depends on the scope where the cast is done. So a private base will pass the check inside the the scope of the derived class, or its friend. On the other hand a *downcast* will always require a public base, and the runtime check will fail for a non-public base (assuming a static check can't be made where the cast is done).

Comment: As T.C. said,"A derived-to-base dynamic_cast is static", does it means that `dynamic_cast` does not always do **run-time check** ?is it  **compile time check** in my example, regardless the word "dynamic" literally?

Comment: @bigxiao - Yes, pretty much. It all depends on the types and the direction of the cast.

Comment: One reason your example doesn't compile is independent of any casts though: The conversion to`A` is simply inaccessible in `main()`. If you befriend main() it should work ;-). (And  make A polymorphic...)

Answer (score 6):

A derived-to-base `dynamic_cast` is static, not dynamic, and only requires the base to be accessible in the context of the cast (and unambiguous). See [[expr.dynamic.cast]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.dynamic.cast#5).

Comment: see  [expr.dynamic.cast]/8: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.dynamic.cast#8

Comment: @YSC That's unreachable for this cast.

Answer (score 1):

The bolded passages are all obviously wrong.

The dynamic cast expression that deals with class types can be logically subdivided in two cases.

- `type` is a class type which is a base class of the *statically determined* type of `e`. In this case dynamic_cast is more or less synonymous with static_cast. In particular, `type` must be an accessible and unambiguous (but not necessarily public) base class of the type of `e`.
- `type` is a class type which is not a base class of the *statically determined* type of `e`. In this case, a runtime check takes place. This is further subdivided to the *downcast* and *crosscast* cases. The differences between those are only important in the case of multiple inheritance and/or non-public inheritance. In either of these cases, `type` must be a type of some subobject of the full object of `e`.

The primer never says whether it means static or dynamic type of `e`, but in either case the description is completely wrong. For the cast to succeed,

- `type` does not need to be related to the *static* type of `e` in any way
- `type` must be a base class of the *dynamic* type of `e` or that type itself (but not a proper derived class of it), with further restrictions related to accessibility and non-ambiguity.