# dynamic_cast fails when cast a derived class to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

In Primer c++ 5th

[image: Markdown]

```
class A {
    public:
        A() : a(1) {}
        virtual ~A() = default;
    private:
        int a;
};
class B : public A {
    public:
        B() : b(2) {}
    private:
        int b;
};
class C : public B {
    public:
        C() : c(3) {}
    private:
        int c;
};
//class D : public B, public A {                   cause error
//    public:
//        D() : d(4) {}
//    private:
//        int d;
//};

int main()
{

    //A *pa = new C;
    //B *pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);          //1st case
    B *pb = new B;
    C *pc = dynamic_cast<C*>(pb);        //2nd case
    cout << pc << endl;
    //A *pa = new D;
    //B *pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);        //3rd case
}
//output: 0     cast failure
```

#### Q1:

Here in the above code .I can understand why the 2nd case doesn't work, but
the type of pb-pointed object is `B` which is the public base class of `C` .And this is the 2nd situation of what's said in Primer c++.
So why the 2nd case doesn't work while primer c++ said this kind of cast will succeed?

#### Q2:

the 3rd case. Errors occurred during compilation

```
error: ‘A’ is an ambiguous base of ‘D’
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: That looks like sloppy writing – what matters is the dynamic type of the object, not the static type of the variable. (Did Lippman really write that?)

Comment: Please ask a question. The post is a bunch of statements, but doesn't currently ask any question.

Comment: @anatolyg add question.

Comment: `class D : public B, public A {` is legal silly useless inheritance: you can't possibly use or refer to the second base

Comment: The error means exactly what it says.   `D` is derived from `B` and from `A`.  `B` is derived from `A`, so `D` actually derives from `A` via two distinct paths.   Effectively this means a `D`'s composition includes two distinct `A`s at separate memory locations.  The mapping from `A *` to a `D *` is different for each inherited `A`, so any conversion from `A *` to `D *` (which happens in `A *pa = new D;`) is ambiguous - the compiler has no reason to prefer one way of conversion over the other.

Comment: This ambiguous passage is also discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381515/is-the-c-primer-making-something-wrong-with-the-usage-of-dynamic-cast

Comment: @SChepurin thanks.one answer states that `type` must be a type of some subobject of the full object of `e`.I can totally understand this.However no one had mentioned about the second cases.

Comment: It produces only warnings when compiled for second case. - "dynamic_cast can also downcast (convert from pointer-to-base to pointer-to-derived) polymorphic classes (those with virtual members) if -and only if- the pointed object is a valid complete object of the target type." With error "an ambiguous base" in third case.

Comment: But if you comment the "virtual..." line, you get "rror: cannot dynamic_cast 'pb' (of type 'class B*') to type 'class C*' (source type is not polymorphic)"

Comment: @SChepurin No warning doesn't mean the cast is succeed.You have to chek if the return pointer by dynamic_cast  is  not 0 then you can find out if the cast is succeed.

Comment: @BAKE ZQ So, show us the code with the errors generated ("... you can find out if the cast is succeed"). Tired to see the questions without code they talk about.

Comment: @BAKE ZQ - It should return null. "You can't cast a base object to a derived type - it isn't of that type. If you have a base type pointer to a derived object, then you can cast that pointer around using dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 2):

in your second example you create a class B, B is a base class for C.

so you can't cast a base class to some derived class.

this will work:

```
 B *pb = new C();
 C *pc = dynamic_cast<C*>(pb);
```

regarding 3rd example D derive from B and A, but B also derive from A, this make problems for compiler. you try to derive 2 times for A, the compiler will not know what function A to use, the base A or the derived version of B. 
al

you should read more about base and derived classes.

Comment: How to explain `e is a public base class of the target type`.Did I misunderstand this sentence.In this case C is a public base class of the taget type (B).

Comment: can you refer to where you read this ? i don't understand the context.

Comment: I showed an image in my question.And that's from primer c++